# Statastates File Not Found

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with state FIPS codes and I want to replace them with state abbreviations. I ran

```
ssc install statastates
statastates, fips(state)
```

and got the following error message:

```
file ~/pathway/statastates.dta not found
r(601);
```

When I rerun `ssc install statastates`, the console tells me "all files already exist and are up to date." Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to this *months* later to post the solution. I can only speak for Mac users, but in my experience, this bug is most often caused by the computer's permission settings.

The error message states that it tried to write a dta file to the folder "/User/Documents/Stata/ado/personal/statastates_data." In other words, either Stata does not have permission to write to this folder or the folder does not exist.

From what I'm able to gather from others' posts, right clicking on the folder and selecting "get info" allows you to change the permissions, which usually works. In my case, the folder did not exist in the specified path, so I simply went to Documents > Stata and created the remaining folders myself. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a bug in these lines of the command:

```
    cap insheet using "`r(fn)'", tab
    cap mkdir "`c(sysdir_personal)'"
    cap mkdir "`c(sysdir_personal)'statastates_data"
    cap save "`c(sysdir_personal)'statastates_data/statastates.dta"
```

Personally I think it is bad practice to include `capture` in commands when non-zero `_rc` codes are not explicitly handled.

The author has included their contact information if you type `ssc describe statastates`. Perhaps reach out to them with your bug.